# How to convert decimal date type column to time data type in power query/power BI?

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, data-transform

[image]

The column consist of minutes that is in the decimal format. This is to be converted to Time format.

**Example:** The 5th record is 61 minutes and 6 seconds.

This is to be displayed as 1 hour, 1 minute and 6 seconds - (01:01:06).

How to solve this problem in power query editor/ power BI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plenty of options. You can do it in Power Query, in DAX as a measure or as a calculated column.

Here is a simple calculated column:

```
Formatted = 
VAR _hrs = QUOTIENT ( [minutes_watched] , 60 )
VAR _mins = INT ( [minutes_watched] - _hrs * 60 )
VAR _sec = MOD ( [minutes_watched] , 1.0 ) * 60
RETURN
FORMAT(_hrs,"00")&":"&FORMAT(_mins,"00")&":"&FORMAT(_sec,"00")
```

This also handles weirdos watching for more than 24 hrs, at which a `TIME` data type would overflow:

[image]

It is also easily written as a measure where the minutes watched can be an aggregation instead:

```
Formatted Minutes := 
VAR _agg_time = [Sum minutes watched] // Aggregation measure of choice goes here
VAR _hrs = QUOTIENT ( _agg_time , 60 )
VAR _mins = INT ( _agg_time - _hrs * 60 )
VAR _sec = MOD ( _agg_time , 1.0 ) * 60
RETURN
FORMAT(_hrs,"00")&":"&FORMAT(_mins,"00")&":"&FORMAT(_sec,"00")
```

Which gives you this result:

[image]

Comment: But here the seconds are captured incorrectly.
Example: 0.3 has to be 3 seconds instead of 18 seconds.

Comment: Your source data lists decimal minutes, so 0.3 minutes is not 3 seconds.

Comment: Or do you propose that some of your data represents e.g. 46 minutes and 80 seconds of watching?

Comment: You are right. Did not realize that earlier. Thank you for providing a comprehensive answer.

Comment: No worries - let's just say I have gone into the same trap before, comparing decimal minutes /km vs. minutes+seconds / km when looking at data from Strava... :D

Answer (score 1):

Simply divide your minutes decimal by (24 * 60) and you can convert it into **Time** format:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromList({"0.3", "2.7", "46.8", "61.6"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(
        Source,{{"Column1", "minutes_watched"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        #"Renamed Columns",{{"minutes_watched", type number}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(
        #"Changed Type", "Custom", each [minutes_watched] / 60 / 24),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        #"Added Custom",{{"Custom", type time}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing a simple and an easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add column ... custom column.. with formula

```
= #duration(0,0,Number.From(Text.Split(Text.From([minutes_watched]),"."){0}),Number.From(Text.Split(Text.From([minutes_watched]),"."){1}))
```